# Which are the other tests/complaints mentioned in Numbers 14:22?

Tags: exodus, numbers, moses

Numbers 14:22

> Surely all the men who have seen My glory and My signs which I performed in Egypt and in the wilderness, yet have put Me to the test these ten times and have not listened to My voice,

Been searching for the ten tests/complaints mentioned in the above text but has only managed to get these listed below:

**1)Exodus 14:10-12 (The Red sea)**

**2)Exodus 15:23 (At Marah)**

**3)Exodus 16:2-10 (Manna and Meat) wilderness of sin**

**4)Exodus 17:1-2 (Massah and Meribah)Rephidim**

**5)Exodus 32:1-35 (Golden calf) Mount Sinai**

**6)Numbers 12:1-16 (Murmuring of Miriam and Aaron) Hazeroth**

**7)Numbers 14:1-45 (Kadesh)**

Looking for the other events which are not listed above?

Comment: I dispute the first three to be part of the list.

Comment: @user21676,had assumed they were part of the ten tests,i stand to be corrected

Comment: Hi Collen, like many of your questions that is a thoughtful one. If the first three items don't belong in the list, perhaps you should edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Ruminator, I thought they were part of the ten tests but somebody seems  to think otherwise,still waiting for him to correct me on those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deuteronomy 9 lists seven instances:

1. v. 7 - in the wilderness, concerning lack of food (Exodus 16)
2. v. 8 - at Horeb, concerning unwillingness to move on towards the promised land (Exodus 33:1-6)
3. vv. 9-21 - the Golden Calf (Exodus 32)
4. v. 22 - at Taberah, concerning complaint about having to rise up every time the Ark went before them (Numbers 10:33-11:3)
5. v. 22 - at Massah, concerning water (Exodus 17:1-7)
6. v. 22 - at Kibrothhattaavah, concerning meat (Numbers 11:4-34)
7. v 23 - at Kadeshbarnea, concerning unwillingness to go in and take the land (Numbers 13)

Besides these, there is also:

1. the complaint concerning Pharaoh's pursuit of the people as they fled towards the Red Sea (Exodus 14:10-12)
2. the rebellion concerning the LORD's command NOT to go in and take the land, but instead to continue on to the Red Sea. (Deuteronomy 1:40-46)
3. the rejection of Moses and the desire of the people to choose a replacement for him to take them back to Egypt, which is additional to their fear about going in and taking the land. (Numbers 14:1-4)

Comment: You both agree on Exd 14(OP 1 = B1), 16(OP 3 = A1?), 17(OP 4 = A5), 32(OP 5 = A3), Num 14(OP 7 = B3), and differ on Exd 15(OP 2 = ?), 32(? = A2), Num 11:1(? = A4);4(? = A6), 12(OP 6 = ?), 13(? = A7), Deu 1(? = B2). I agree with A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, B3, Op 6; A2 however should be combined with A3, B2 is a repitition of A7, and B1(along with Op 1/2/3) seem to be uncounted as per the context(e.g. necessity). If A1 is split into two(Exd 16:19, 16:26) then this adds to nine. The remaining tenth then would seem to be attributed to Nadab and Abihu(Leviticus 10:1).

Comment: @user21676 Submit your suggestion as an answer. Be sure to phrase it as your own list, not as an amalgam of the OP's and mine. The nature of the question lends itself to answers that will have points in common.

Answer (score 3):

> Which are the other tests/complaints mentioned in Numbers 14:22?

That assumes it existed really/only 10 times.

Another interpretation of that passage is the 10 are a stylistic feature to mean many times.

The same happens for instance in Genesis 31:7 (NASB)

> Yet your father has cheated me and changed my wages **ten times**; however, God did not allow him to do me harm.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahim thank you, well spotted!